# Name of series with bounded neighbor difference

Tags: sequences-and-series

> For a series $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$, with $|x_i - x_{i-1}| < M$ for $i>1$, where $M$ is a constant.

---

Is there a formal name of this kind of series?

Comment: What you have written is a sequence and not a series, and as far as I know there is no name for such a sequence.

Comment: No. ${}{}{}{}{}$